# How to add billing account to google map platform

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i try to add billing account to google map platform it did not add it gives me error that correct your card info although it is correct but it gives me this error

Please give me some solution for this if anyone know i am stuck very badly so give me some solutions

Comment: For this kind of issue, it is best to reach out to the [support of Google Maps platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support).